# mdev doesn't seem to be working on reboot

Tags: linux-kernel, udev, ethernet, hot-plug

Our Linux Kernel is 3.10 running on an embedded mips processor with busybox.
The init script has -

```
echo "/sbin/mdev" > /proc/sys/kernel/hotplug
mdev -s
```

We have a rule to rename a network interface of USB to Ethernet adapter on seeing a ADD action. 
On hotplugging the adapter, I see that the interface does get renamed but the same does not happen on reboot.